# IE crash on closing

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, crash

Whenever I use close the IE (IE8) after browsing I get a crash like this:

[image: IE Crash]

It looks like MS are not trusting themself. Is there any way I can fix it? (Other than using firefox or chrome that is.)

Comment: Have look : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371730(VS.85).aspx

Comment: No FF or Chrome? Use Opera! :P

Comment: @Phoshi: you should have been posting this comment as answer, since you've got plenty of karma to burn. :P

Comment: and i wonder if the OP got here by clicking on the link 'What should I do?' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be an addon misbehaving. Try running IE with no addons(it's buried in your start menu under Accessories->System Tools) and see if the problem persists. If it does not, disable add ons one at a time until you find the culprit

Comment: Yes disabling add ons worked..although I don't know which one caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disable memory Protection option in Internet Explorer options -> in advanced tab

(or)

Have look on this "[How do I turn off Data Execution Prevention errors?](http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_turn_off_data_execution_prevention_errors.html)"

Answer (score 0):

Disable addons separately, one by one. If you have IE 7 or 8 you can access them through Tools -> Internet Options -> Programs -> Manage Addons. You can then disable/enable single addon. If you have many it can take you quite some time, but at least you'll know which addon is problematic.